# I cannot add a file system to lambda (access denied)

Tags: aws-lambda, permissions, amazon-iam, amazon-efs

At https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=us-east-1#/functions/PaidProxyFunc/create/elastic-file-system?tab=configure "Add file system", when I click Save to add an EFS file system to my lambda function,

> You do not have sufficient permission. Access denied.

What permissions should I add and to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Lambda function needs:

- role with basic permissions
- AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
- AmazonElasticFileSystemClientReadWriteAccess

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-a-shared-file-system-for-your-lambda-functions/